# Zend and phpThumb - Upload Images of a given product or article

Tags: zend-framework, image-processing, file-upload

Let's say I know how to upload an image using Zend.
Let's say I know how to generate the thumbs of that image using phpThumb class integrated with Zend.

Where (controller, helper?) **should** we then associate that image with a given database record? Should or product or article database table have a field called img path and another called thumb path ? Or should we store the images on a the database?

I'm not looking into specifics here, just a general way of doing it, so that I could understand what is a common way of archieving it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this:

1. Save the path of the original image in a mysql varchar field
2. Create a resize controller
3. Disable the view and the layout from the controller
4. Get the path of the image via $this->_getParam('img');
5. Validation
6. Resize the image
7. Show the image
8. Inside a view script i call img src="/resize?img=image.jpg"

edit: Usually, in combination with this, i write a custom route to avoiding the ugly url being displayed in the source code of the page

Comment: Thanks. What if you deal with several images per product or article ? We should perhaps create a table called prod_images and associate that with the product, so that one product could have several images, precise? About the controller usage... I'm not sure. I mean, does that imply that we need to instantiate the controller again and again (you are not extending I suppose). Wouldn't be better to use an Action Helper ? I mean, by using a helper class, you take care of all the business on one place, and then, depending on the view, you call them. Or this is a bad approach ?

Comment: Well if you have a OneToMany association between an article and images is quite same, you iterate over the images list and simply echo them. For the controller usage, usually when i got a lot of images (and articles ofc) to display, i paginate them so you actually display 10 or 20 images..and its not a big load. If you use an helper class, that's an additional load for the server because it will instantiate every time you need to echo an image. I think there isn't a best approach for that..

Comment: Thanks a lot Cristian. I will think about it for a moment but that list sure will help me out. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

We usually have some concrete directory for saving images (like /public_html/images) and there we store the originals (usually resized to some max. size - say 1024px - upon uploading). There are also subdirectories there, called medium and small (for product detail and small thumbnail for category list).

We also store the images using products primary key (if products:images is 1:1) or using PK + id (for 1:N). Then we easily assemble the url in img() view helper like this.

```
public function img($product, $imageId, $size = self::SMALL) {
    return sprintf('/images/%s/%s_%s.jpg', $size, $product->id, $imageId);
}

//in view - can also be wrapped in view helper - depends on your scenario
<a href="<?php echo $this->img($product, 1, 'big');?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->img($product, 1, 'small');?>" /></a>
```

**Edit:** BTW: Actually we never use the originals. We make "big" sized images.

The action helper for image resizing is generally a good idea. But depends on how you upload your images - if there is only one action and one controller - there is no need AFAIK. But you may want to upload images also from import, using FTP upload, etc.

The linking (if the process described abowe doesn't work well for you) of images via DB falls to two categories - content centric and image centric.

You can either go into product editing, where is a button or like "upload a new image" or "link uploaded image". Other option is to have a list of images with "connect to a product". Highly dependable on your users' workflow.

Also there are some options how to build your db. You can have image_id in your product table. Or you can have imalelink_id in you product table, which links to M:N table that connects images to products. Also you can have product_id in your image table :) All of these approaches are valid in some cases and wrong in some other. All depends on how the end users will use it.

Comment: It seems a very nice approach as well. You need then, to call that image, later on some specific views, right? So, you echo the returned value from your view helper on each view. Or am I not getting something? Thanks

Comment: got it. :) thanks for the clarifications. One last question: :) What are those /%s/%s_%s for ? Thanks again.

Comment: It's normal `sprintf()` syntax. I like to use it as it's easier to read: `sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $url, $title)` then `'<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>'` I'm also much less likely to make a mistake in the markup that way.

Comment: I tend to mess up the quotes when using normal string concat :)